# What's the difference between productID and gtin/mpn (http://schema.org/Product)

Tags: schema.org

Under the [Product](http://schema.org/Product) schema type, there are multiple ways of identifying a product:

- `gtin12`
- `gtin13`
- `gtin14`
- `gtin8`
- `mpn`

So why does the `productID` property exist? Isn't this a little redundant?

Comment: productID supports any identifier... the ones you listed are strict and must use the supported type, I.E ISBN can be used in GTIN-13, while a uncommon identifier may not be supported in any of those you listed, therefore you can use it in productID, e.g `meta itemprop="productID" content="ProWebmasters:98357"`.

Comment: that seems like a solid answer!

Comment: Just added it as an answer with a little bit more quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTIN 8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14 and MPN are all common global and local identifiers which replace a wide range of previous popular identifiers.

> [SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number#Format)
>
> - GTIN-14 Former name(s): DUN-14, ITF
> - GTIN-13 Former name(s): EAN·UCC-13, EAN-13, CIP
> - GTIN-12 Former name(s): EAN·UCC-12, UCC-12, UPC
> - GTIN-8 Former name(s): EAN·UCC-8, EAN-8

It's worth mentioning that ISBN was superseded by EAN, and EAN was superseded by GTIN-13. On the 1st of January 2005 the U.S. ISBN agency requires publishers be able to communicate ISBNs as GTIN-13.

However, Schema allows the use of [product ISBN](https://schema.org/isbn) for older books, you could use productID, or ISBN, both are correct. [ProductID](https://schema.org/productID) is an less specific product identifier, you could use GTIN, MPM or another identifier that is not supported by GTIN, such as '[Product ID BRAND](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161?hl=en-GB#types)'.

You will find that with Schema there is often times that you will find markup that can be approached in different ways, however the outcome remains the same, and correct.